# Paypal subscription. Send an email with the paid invoice to a user after the user has been charged for a subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions, payment-processing

I am creating a payment system for a small SaaS Startup. We want to provide a trial period for our service, **when a user subscribes using the Paypall subscription**. To be complient with the law, we have to send an invoice, stating the length of the trial period. The invoice should state, **that it has already been paid**.
I recently subscribed to Overleaf and the invoice, that they send seems perfect for my goal, so I attach an image as an example.
[image: Overleaf invoice]

The problem I have with paypal is that it has separate payment options for subscription and invoices.

In the RESP API docs https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/ there is no information about invoicing after the user has subscribed even though this is a very common scenario for the subscription event flow. Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to implement it.